# How to "join" a table twice with just one join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's hard for me to explain this one so you're likely confused by the title.
But I'll try my best here.

Say we have the following scenario:

**Tests Table**

- Test ID
- testtakenby(id)
- testrevisedby(id)

## Users

- User ID
- Username

Is there a way for me to be able to get the following result:

"Test was taken by user1 and revised by user2"

Without having to join the tables twice?
Like this:

```
select * from tests
inner join users on tests.testtakenby = users.userid
inner join users on tests.testrevisedby = users.userid
```

I'm hoping there is an advanced SQL trick of getting it done as I worry of possible performance issues by joining the same table twice (I presume it wouldn't perform as well with a double join)

Comment: if you have performance issues, you should look for correct indexes not changing your solution.

Comment: I dont think there is, and why would there be a performance issue with joining twice?

Comment: you need to alias the second instance of users - if that is the problem - another solution is to have two sub-queries in a select

Comment: the double join shouldn't be anymore of a performance problem than the single join - if the single join works well, then so should the double join - have you got indexes/primary keys on userid?

Comment: I've not got performance issues as of yet and the query won't be bringing in enough records for it to be a noticeable issue. My mindset was more like 'Joining the same table twice? there must be a better way'. Being a Junior dev I thought I'd ask you guys. It's also my first question ever. I thought there would be a decrease in performance. Thanks for clarifying it isn't though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two joins should perform just fine and there is no alternate double join syntax

Answer (score 0):

To correct your join (since your join will result in errors):

```
select * from tests
inner join users Taken 
on tests.testtakenby = Taken.userid
inner join users Revised
on tests.testrevisedby = Revised.userid
```

and no I guess there is no way to join a table twice with one join.

Answer (score -1):

```
select (SELECT u1.UserName FROM users u1 WHERE u1.userid = tests.testtakenby) As takenBy,
       (SELECT u2.UserName FROM users u2 WHERE u2.userid = tests.testrevisedby) As RevisedBy
from tests
```

however this gives no performance benefits I know of - it's considered aesthetically worse - NULL would appear if there was no match on testtakenby or testrevisedby - in an INNER JOIN, there would be no record selected

Answer (score -1):

Why in the world would you like to prevent using 2 joins? That is exaclty the correct concept and your SQL engine should do its part.

Comment: Because I'm not that experienced in SQL and aim to improve myself by asking questions to those who will likely know more than I do.